# How can i add rel="nofollow" in img tags?

Tags: seo, google, links

Does it make sense to have a rel="nofollow" attribute in img tag?

Do search engines' crawlers use this attribute in some way for calculating PageRank score?

What is the practical sense for using it (if any)?

Our site is about immigration to Canada in 2 languages and we use a flag image " How can I add a no-follow tag to our flag image? "

in English, we use the Canada flag for **immigration to Canada** and in Farsi we use the Iran flag for **مشاور رسمی مهاجرت به کانادا : https://fa.meritrusts.com/**

we want to separate these two from each other[image]

Comment: You would use nofollow in the href link of the image link: <a href="canada.html" rel="nofollow"><img src="flag-canada.jpg"></a>

Answer (score 3):

It does not make sense to use nofollow on an image tag, particularly in your case.

First of all, rel="nofollow" is mostly a waste of time, as far as Pagerank goes: https://www.thesearchreview.com/page-rank-sculpting-does-not-work-15217/

Relevant quote from John Mueller: "...In general, I think it's a waste of time to do that. In practice, people waste their time on it anyway."

Additionally, nofollow was created for links leading to external web sources whose content you either do not trust or is paid. So if you wanted to site a website you don't want to pass any link juice to, or if you have an advertising link, it makes sense to nofollow. If your image links to a trustworthy web source, either internal of external, why nofollow it, if as Mueller says, it's a waste of time for ranking purposes? And if it just links to a picture hosted on your server, it definitely makes no sense at all to use nofollow. So, don't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you for your complete and professional answer.